# How to do power analysis for 1-5 ranked data?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-power

I'm currently designing an online questionnaire, where I'm going to ask online raters to rate N samples in group 1 (i.e speech from native English speakers) and N samples in group 2 (i.e speech from non-native English speakers) on a 1-5 scale. The samples are randomised in order, and the raters are unaware of the groups. The samples are independent of each other, i.e the content of each utterance is different (this means that paired tests are not appropriate here).

My initial intuition was that this is a Mann-Whitney test due to the ranked nature of the data, and a lot of the standard analysis in the literature uses the Mann-Whitney test for my kind of data, but because of the limited scale [1,5], I'm having doubts.

As far as I know, this is a power analysis question.

I want to determine N with the criteria to obtain significance:

- which test to use (Mann-Whitney, Mood's median test, Kruskal Wallis)
- p < 0.05 level
- expecting a unit difference in the median (3 vs 4 or 4 vs 5)